# Does Apache calcite support connection pool?

Tags: java, sql-server, apache-calcite

I'm a beginner in Apache Calcite and I need to create multiple SQL statements in minimum time so I need to make connection pool to calcite connection to execute my statements.
so I need to know if Apache calcite supports connection pool, or if I need to execute a statement I'll need to create a new connection and close it again?
if it supports connection pool please mention a simple example.
thanks